# Allure update error. Lru/yandex/qatools/allure/junit/TestSuiteReportRule

Tags: java, junit, webdriver, allure

I updated Allure ver from 1.2.2 to 1.4.
And now I have an error, executing *mvn clean test*.

Stack:

### ` T E S T S

Running qwer.selenium.LoginTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.065 sec <<< FAILURE! - in qwer.selenium.LoginTest
initializationError(qwer.selenium.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 0.016 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lru/yandex/qatools/allure/junit/TestSuiteReportRule;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.(TestClass.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.TestSuiteReportRule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.(TestClass.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)`

pom.xml:
`
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>qwer</groupId>
<artifactId>qwer</artifactId>
<version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!--Allure version, needed here for allure-maven-plugin. It can be moved to parent pom.-->
<properties>
    <allure.version>1.4.0</allure.version>
    <selenium.version>2.42.2</selenium.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!--This dependency is necessary for Allure JUnit plugin. It can be moved to parent pom.-->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.properties</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-loader</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlelements-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!--Allure JUnit plugin. It can be moved to parent pom. -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>allure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/RawTest.*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/OutboxDocumentTest.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!--Allure Maven Plugin. It can be moved to parent pom-->
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the feedback

First of all, remove **allure-junit-plugin** from your project configuration. It's solve your problem

Then change version of **allure-maven-plugin** to **2.0**.

---

*Also you can read migration guide from 1.3.* to 1.4* https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Upgrading-to-1.4

*PS today we release allure version 1.4.1*

Comment: Thanks!
I had made changes and add 
'
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>'
in maven-surefire-plugin section.

All works!
You as always the best!

Comment: Yep, forgot about surefire plugin configuration